# Can I use multi-threading to speed up a method operation?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following model for the hotel data,

```
public class HotelData {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String stars;
    private String contact;
    private String phone;
    private String uri;


    public HotelData(String name, String address, String stars, String contact, String phone, String uri) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.stars = stars;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public HotelData() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getStars() {
        return stars;
    }

    public void setStars(String stars) {
        this.stars = stars;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
```

And, I use the following method that uses the List rows to convert in the JSON format.

```
@Override
    public void dataToJsonConverter() {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            String jsonInString = "";

            for (HotelData hotels : rows) {
                jsonInString += mapper.writeValueAsString(hotels);
            }

            mapper.writeValue(new File(Constant.OUTPUT_LOC +  "/result.json"), jsonInString);
//            jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(hotelData);


        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("CONVERTED TO JSON");
    }
```

However, the data volume is huge and its taking several seconds for the conversion. Can I use the multi-threading to speed up the process and how then? I don't have lot of experience with threading, so, please accept apology if the question is not appropriate. I just want to speed up the data conversation.

UPDATE: Surprisingly, the `StringBuilder` is about 25 times faster than the `String`. WOW

Comment: Speed up which process? The writing to a file? Then the answer is "no"

Comment: This line `            mapper.writeValue(new File(Constant.OUTPUT_LOC +  "/result.json"), jsonInString);` write the data to the JSON file. If this is not possible, how about speed up the for loop ? I will be very helpful if I could improve the performance.

Comment: Before the threading, is there anyway you can avoid writing to the file ? or minimise it. . It will be a bottleneck  regardless multi-threading.

Comment: @Xenwar What do you mean? I need a output file anyway.

Comment: Well,you can do it once in 1000 rounds. File I/O is expensive and only one thread can do it at a time, making you code sequential. So, save it in memory and write is once in 1000 round.

Comment: If the bottleneck is writing to the disk, then you can't speed that up with multithreading. The disk can only write as fast as it can write. You could consider compressing the data in-memory, and writing the _compressed_ datastructure to disk instead.

Comment: You could optimize the `for` loop a bit by using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of concatenating two strings

Comment: `jsonInString += mapper.writeValueAsString(hotels);` that is extremely inefficient: it creates a copy of the whole string at each iteration. Open a buffered writer to the file, and write each object directly to the writer. Or better, to have valid JSON in the file, write the whole list instead of each object.

Comment: You need to profile this and find out where the performance bottleneck is. For example, if you want to check what is performance cost of _serializing the datastructure_: try writing to an output stream that _isn't_ a file. Isolate and measure each step.

Comment: @UnholySheep : compiler will internally replace string concatenation into StringBuilder in resulting bytecode

Comment: @rkosegi no, it won't.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is way more faster though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multithreading isn't impossible, but will massively complicate this. If the methods are to be complicated anyway, I propose a method that's just faster to begin with. (And doesn't come with the baggage parallel solutions have to deal with)

The stringification is undoubtly so slow because of the reflection used in ObjectMapper. If you're up for some extra programming, the next solution is way faster. However it isn't as generic.

```
public interface JSONNable {
     String toJSON();
}


public class HotelData implements JSONNable {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String stars;
    private String contact;
    private String phone;
    private String uri;


    public HotelData(String name, String address, String stars, String contact, String phone, String uri) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.stars = stars;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public HotelData() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getStars() {
        return stars;
    }

    public void setStars(String stars) {
        this.stars = stars;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String toJSON() {
        return String.format("{\"name\" : \"%s\", \"address\" : \"%s\", \"stars\" : \"%s\", \"contact\" : \"%s\", \"phone\" : \"%s\", \"uri\" : \"%s\"}", 
           name, address, stars, contact, phone, uri);
    }

    /* or any other iterable<HotelData> hotels, including an array */
    public static String hotelsToJSON(ArrayList<HotelData> hotels) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append('[');
        for (HotelData hotelData : hotels) {
            sb.append(hotel.toJSON());
            sb.append(',');
        }
        sb.insert(sb.length() - 1, ']');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Note that in creating a new interface and implementing the toJSON() method, there doesn't have to be a runtime analysis of the HotelData Object (which is slow). The difference in execution time costs you extra time programming though.

Comment: This doubles the performance than the `StringBuilder`. The worst performance was with `String`

Answer (score 0):

The write to file operation cannot be speeded up with multithreading. The only thing you could speed up is the JSON conversion of the data. You can achieve that by using a ForkJoinPool or an ExecuterService to the split the data among several threads to process them. At the end you can gather then the JSON strings and then write them to a file.

Here you can find a tutorial how to use a ForkJoinPool and how is generally works:
[ForkJoinPool Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/java-fork-and-join-forkjoinpool.html)

EDIT

I only have an example for sorting a big array

Here you can see a RecursiveTask used by the ForkJoinPool to sort the data and some helper methods

```
    // class used to store job results
class SortedArray
{
private int [] array;

public void setArray(int [] array)
{
    this.array = array;
}
public int[] getArray()
{
    return this.array;
}
}


class Sort  extends RecursiveTask<SortedArray>
{
        // blocksize that is used to decide whenever insertionsort 
        //      is used or more splits are necessary
static final int BlockSize = 100;
private int lb,ub;
private int [] data;
public Sort(int lb, int ub, int[] data)
{
    this.lb  = lb;
    this.ub  = ub;
    this.data = data;
}

protected SortedArray compute() {
        // if array size is smaller than the blocksize 
    if((ub - lb) <= BlockSize)
    {
        // do insertionSort in the segment
        insertionSort(this.data, lb, ub);
    }
        // if array size is bigger than the blocksize
    else
    {
        if(lb+1 < ub){
        // compute mid value for split
            int mid = (lb+ub)/2;
        // create new job for the left segment
            Sort left = new Sort(this.lb,mid,this.data);
        // create new job for the right segment
            Sort right = new Sort(mid,this.ub,this.data);
        // wait for the first job
            left.fork();
        // wait for the second job
            right.fork();
        // redeem data from the first job
            SortedArray arr1 = left.join();
        // redeem data from the second job
            SortedArray arr2 = right.join();
        // merge the data
            merge(this.data,lb,mid,ub);
        }
    }
        // create SortedArray object to store result
    SortedArray sArr = new SortedArray();
        // set result
    sArr.setArray(this.data);
        // return result
    return sArr;
  }
        // given method
 private void insertionSort(int dt[], int a, int b){
 for(int i = a; i < b; i++){
     int j = i;
     while(j > a && dt[j] < dt[j-1]){
            int temp = dt[j]; dt[j] = dt[j-1]; dt[j-1] = temp;
            j--;
     }
 }
 }

private void merge(int f[], int lb, int mid, int ub){
  int c[] = new int[ub-lb];
    int k = 0;int j = lb; int h = mid;
    while(j < mid && h < ub){
        if(f[j] <= f[h]){
            c[k] = f[j];
            j++;
        }
        else{
            c[k] = f[h];
            h++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(j < mid){ c[k] = f[j];  k++; j++; }
    while(h < ub){c[k] = f[h]; k++; h++;}
    //Now copy data back to array
    for(int p = 0; p < c.length;p++)
        f[lb+p] = c[p];
}
}
```

and here the example usage

```
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


        // create the array
int [] arr = new int [10000000];
for(int i = 0; i< arr.length;i++)
{
        // fill the array with random values
    arr[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10000000);
}



        // create a ForkJoinPool
ForkJoinPool fjPool = new ForkJoinPool();
        // invoke the sort and store the result in the SortedArray class
SortedArray sortedArr = fjPool.invoke(new Sort(0, arr.length, arr));




endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
runningTime = endTime-startTime;





System.out.println("============================================");
System.out.println("Arraysize: " + arr.length);
System.out.printf("ForkJoinpool contains %d Threads\n",fjPool.getPoolSize());
System.out.println("Running time: "+runningTime + " millisecs (" +(runningTime/1000.0) + ") secs");
System.out.println("============================================");
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Thanks, can you have some sample code with this answer ?

Comment: Sure i will look if i have a sample

Answer (score -1):

If conversion logic is taking time and you think writing to file is not a overhead, then you can initiate (say)n threads and assign totalHotel/n hotels to each thread to convert.

There are 2 approaches to write to file. A. Each thread will write to it's own file. B. all threads write to a single file. Approach B would need synchronization, and if you are sure writing is not time-consuming that conversion logic, OTHERWISE you would get worse running time in approach B, if conversion is faster and for writing all threads are waiting for the current thread to finish writing.

If approach A is used ,then you'll need to write new code to merge the files and handle the proper prefix and suffix for file single output file accordingly.

---

```
class Worker implements Runnable {
   public void run() {

   }
}
```

This is basic worker runnable class, that you can create as below and pass few hotel objects to it to convert to json in the `run` method.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Worker());
....
t.start();
```

You can pass any additional data via constuctor or any other method before calling start on the thread `t`.

Comment: How is that each thread have its own file ? what file name would it have ?

Comment: @Xenwar each thread can write to any temporary file say tmp<n>.txt and for file-reading writing http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()

Comment: Oh I thought you said it with the current context. Even then, it will create another problem. According to Qn, the data is huge and you may not have enough INODEs available, to mention one of the problems.